# Cocoapods 1.0 breaks FileMerge

Tags: cocoapods, emoji, filemerge

A bit of background:

My team upgraded to cocoapods 1.0 on our main develop branch. After it was committed and push I tried to merge it into my branch. There was a merge conflict in the `project.pbxproj`. I tried to fix the conflict with FileMerge. After FileMerge opened it would not load up the program. Right clicking on the icon revealed the `Application Not Responding` message.

Through the research that I've done, the problem is with FileMerge. It can't handle the case when there is a difference on a line that contains an emoji. I've submitted a bug report to Apple, and I've also created an issue on the cocoapods github page (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5374).

I hope that this will save you time figuring out why FileMerge is randomly broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, Cocoapods has updated the repository, and fixed the issue.